# Asociar permisos a roles en laravel con paquete spatie usando Collective Select múltiples

Tags: laravel-7, laravelcollective, spatie

Estoy haciendo un crud para asignar permisos a roles, en laravel 7, con el paquete de roles y permisos Spatie permissions.

Ya tengo hecho un crud que me permiten dar de alta los roles y otro crud que me permite dar de alta los permisos. Ahora estoy tratando de implementar el crud que me permitirá asociar permisos a un rol.

La vista index es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar clic al botón Asignar permisos, invoca el método edit del controlador:

```
    public function edit(Role $permrol)
{
    $permissions=Permission::pluck('name','id');

    \Log::info('Entrando a EDIT');
    \Log::info('$permrol: '.$permrol);
    \Log::info('$permission: '.$permissions);

    return view('admin.permrol.edit', compact('permrol','permissions'));
}
```

La variable $permrol es un registro del modelo Role y corresponde a la del rol, seleccionado.

La vista que se invoca es:

```
@section('content') 
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">     
        <label>Rol</label>       
        <p class="form-control">{{$permrol->name}}</p>
        <br>    
        <label for="roles">Permisos</label>

        {!! Form::model($permrol,['route'=>['permrol.update',$permrol], 'method'=>'put']) !!}
            
            {!! Form::select('permission[]', $permissions, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class'=>'form-control', 'size'=>'15', 'placeholder' => 'Seleccione los permisos a asignar al rol ...']) !!}

            {!! Form::submit('Asignar permiso',['class'=>'btn btn-info mt-3']) !!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

y se despliega la vista edit:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se está produciendo la primera falla y es que si el rol seleccionado ya tiene permisos asignados, deberían aparecer seleccionados en el listbox, pues estoy usando collective binding model.

En esta vista puedo seleccionar uno o varios permisos para asociarlo al rol seleccionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar clic al botón "Asignar permiso", se invoca el método update del controlador, el cual tiene:

```
public function update(Request $request, Role $permrol)
{
    \Log::info('En Update, $permrol: '.$permrol);
    \Log::info('En Update, $permission: '.$request->permissions);

    $permrol->permissions()->sync($request->permissions);

    return redirect()->route('permrol.index');
}
```

Aquí se produce la segunda falla, pues no se actualiza le relación de permisos con roles.

Mirando el log de laravel, para cuando entra al método update, veo que llega correcto la información del rol, pero no llega la información de los permisos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el primer problema, no sé por qué se está produciendo; tal vez sea que la forma como debe cargar la información de permisos en el SELECT múltiple, le falta algo.

Para el segundo problema, tiendo a pensar que el problema está en el SELECT múltiple, pero no sé cuál es.

Agradezco toda ayuda que me permita solucionar estos dos problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Revisando, encontré el error:

```
{!! Form::select('permission[]', $permissions, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class'=>'form-control', 'size'=>'15', 'placeholder' => 'Seleccione los permisos a asignar al rol ...']) !!}
```

permission[]   debe ser permissions[], faltaba una 's' al nombre.

Con eso funcionó.
Lo dejo por si puedes servir a alguien.